# Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test vs $t$-test Power Simulation

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, simulation, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, statistical-power

It is well known that the Wilcoxon rank sum test is more powerful for detecting shifts in location when the data is non-normal. However, I am conducting a brief simulation study and my results contradict this.

One setting in my simulation strategy is as follows:

- Generate 25 random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_{25}$ such that $X\sim\mathsf{exp}(\mu=1)$
- Generate 25 random variables $Y_1,\ldots,Y_{25}$ such that $Y\sim\mathsf{exp}(\mu=1.5)$
- Determine whether the null hypothesis that $\mu_X=\mu_Y$ is rejected
- Repeat 10,000 and calculate the average

This average gives the empirical power of the test. However, I find that the $t$-test is consistently more powerful than the Wilcoxon rank sum test. For instance, in my last simulation, I obtained powers of 0.2317 and 0.2585 for the Wilcoxon and $t$-test, respectively.

Is there a flaw in my simulation strategy that is leading to unintuitive results? My R code:

```
power=0
for(i in 1:10000){
  x   <- rexp(25,1/1)
  y   <- rexp(25,1/1.5)
  res <- wilcox.test(x, y, alternative = "two.sided")
  power=power+(res$p.value<0.05)
}
power/10000

power=0
for(i in 1:10000){
  x   <- rexp(25,1/1)
  y   <- rexp(25,1/1.5)
  res <- t.test(x, y, alternative = "two.sided")
  power=power+(res$p.value<0.05)
}
power/10000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say "*It is well known that the Wilcoxon rank sum test is more powerful for detecting shifts in location when the data is non-normal*" but stated so generally, this is not actually the case. It is not well known at all (for all that it might be widely believed), because it's not true.

For some non-normal distributions, sure, but not for all of them.

For example, with a beta(2,2) distribution, the relative power for the Wilcoxon vs t is even worse than it is at the normal (specifically, the asymptotic relative efficiency is about 86% vs about 95% at the normal).

Generally speaking the Wilcoxon will beat the t on power with shift alternatives on  heavier-tailed symmetric distributions, but outside that it's sometimes less powerful. What makes it a good choice, however, is that it's not *much* less powerful (while the t can sometimes be much less powerful than the Wilcoxon).

---

I should point out that your code does not compare a location shift alternative; you have a change of scale there. A location shift could be obtained by adding something to the y-values instead.

(However, with strictly positive random variables, changes of scale may well make more sense to investigate, since those may more typically be the sort of thing you would see.)

---

However, one thing to note when comparing under such situations is that the type I error rate (actual significance level) of the t can be impacted - which will move the whole power curve up or down. To my mind it would make sense to consider separately the effect on $α$ and the effect on power at the same true significance level. This involves figuring out the effect on the significance level first and then adjusting the nominal significance level to compare power at the same true significance level, so that you're correctly interpreting the cause (e.g. is a lower rejection rate mainly due to conservatism or is it lower curvature of the power function?).

---

You can do slightly better in your simulation by comparing on the *same* samples. This reduces the variation. For the power comparison you were using in your question, you could do something like this:

```
lam1 <- 1/1.0; n1 <- 25
lam2 <- 1/1.5; n2 <- 25
nsim <- 10000
ps <- replicate(nsim,{
        x=rexp(n1,lam1)
        y=rexp(n2,lam2)
        c(wp=wilcox.test(x,y)$p.value,tp=t.test(x,y)$p.value)})
(power<-rowMeans(ps<=0.05))
```

Comment: I thought the Wilcoxon test would shine in the exponential case because the distribution is one-sided. Instead I should consider something like the Cauchy distribution?

Comment: I just tried this where $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim\mathsf{Cauchy}(0,1)$ and obtained powers of $0.0201$ and $0.0549$ for the $t$-test and Wilcoxon test, respectively. Are there any other distributions you think I should consider?

Comment: You have no location shift there, so you're looking at the null (and two different distributions for X and Y, so the assumptions of both tests under the null don't hold).

Comment: To see the Wilcoxon beat the t, try two of the *same* distribution, apart from a location shift. e.g. two logistic distrubutions or two sech distributions or two t-distributions with low d.f. (say $t_3$, or even Cauchy).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! This was really helpful. I've been taught in the past that if the assumptions don't hold for a $t$-test then use a Wilcoxon test. Does that advice skip over important details? I suppose there's a difference between using a valid test and a test meant to identify true alternatives.

Comment: Just making sure I understand you correctly - do you mean to first compute the type I error rate of *each* test and then compute the power under the *respective* empirical significance levels?

Comment: 1. That advice has a number of issues - not least of which it's asking you to choose what test to use on the basis of looking at the data, which itself screws with the properties of both tests you're choosing between. Even putting that issue aside, I wouldn't limit my alternatives to using a t-test *only* to the Wilcoxon. 2. No, I meant to adjust the nominal level of one so that the attained signifiicance level is the same for both in the power comparison. If you know one test is more conservatve, naturally it will tend to have lower power; ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... whats more interesting is whether that's almost all of the effect on power or not

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Is there an obvious way to update the nominal level other than trial and error?

Comment: If you adjust the t, trial and error is pretty much it (well, actually you can do better than naked trial and error but it would take several attempts to get it). However, if you know the significance level of the t you can do the Wilcoxon at that level. Or at least you *could* if the Wilcoxon itself were not discrete; it too is not operating at exactly $\alpha$ (which you should *also* worry about for the same reason as adjusting for the possible impact on the t).

Comment: Going back to your earlier question on whether the advice to choose the Wilcoxon was leaving out important considerations, if you do limit yourself to just those two options, you may still have some idea of the general distribution shape (before seeing these specific samples) and so (at least if you've done a lot of power comparisons at different dstributions, sample sizes and effect sizes) may have a better sense of when to choose which.

Comment: But there are other possible tests, both parametric and nonparametric -- not least I would note that you can use the t in a permutation test for example, which at least solves the impact on significance level (aside from the discreteness issue, which is only much of a problem at small samples). For me my first consideration (when I use hypothesis tests at all) is generally related to very careful consideration of null and alternative.

Comment: I'll take this into consideration in my study. Thank you - this was very informative!

Comment: Oh, one thing I meant to point out before but lost it amongst all the other issues was the fact that your code didn't actually compare power on a shift alternative; that's a change of scale, rather than location. I've now specifically noted it in my answer.

Comment: So my test is still sensible but I just need to be careful with my wording and call it a *parameter* shift? A location shift would be something like $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)+c$?

Comment: It is sensible, but yes, it's a change of scale; you could call that a parameter shift. With a normal as in your comment you can directly shift the mean ($Y\sim N(c,1)$) but with an exponential, you would get a location shift - if you wanted one - by adding $c$ (it doesn't have a location parameter). It would be unusual to see that actually going on in many situations where you see exponential-looking distributions though